# Replacing fried relay for solenoid valve

Tags: motor, circuit-design, relay, solenoid-valve

I have a sink faucet that operates with a capacitive sensor, if I touch anywhere on the sink it turns the water on, or off. After around a minute it automatically turns off if left on.

The sensor connects to some kind of relay with a single wire (no positive/negative pair), which is also connected to the 6v dc in, and the solenoid valve out. I have observed that reversing the polarity of the current to the valve allows me to open/close it. The valve will stay open closed until I apply the opposite polarity current. Is the capacitive sensor reversing the polarity, and the current then discharging to close the valve again?

I have read about h-bridges and dpdt relays. My question is, could I replace the fried component controlling the solenoid valve with one of these components? Would I need a resistor to have the valve shut off after a set time?

[image: The 6v power has two wires (positive/neutral), the sensor wire has only a single wire that changes from 0.15v to 0.10v when a hand touches the faucet]

Comment: yes, an H-bridge is probably what is being used, if reversal if polarity is required ... it is most likely controlled by a microcontroller ... why do you believe that a resistor is required to shut off the valve?

Comment: are you really certain that the polarity of the control votage has to be reversed to open and close the valve? ... did you try multiple re-connections without reversing the wires?

Comment: Does the solenoid have a return spring to shutoff water?  Is the battery worn out?  Is there a reverse flyback clamp diode to protect the contacts from arcing from the solenoid inductance?  If so, then a single pole relay is all that is used and worn out.  If the valve stays open without current, then the spring is worn out

Comment: @Jsotola yes, if I disconnect and reconnect the valve stays opened/closed. It only changes states when I reverse the polarity.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I opened up the valve, there is no spring. The batteries wore out for the second time after only a month, so I replaced them, resulting to the best of my knowledge in the relay being fried. The valve did open before closing again and staying closed until I hooked it up directly to a dc adapter.

Comment: you said that there is a relay ... perhaps it has DPDT contacts and is used as an H-bridge ... the application of power is handled by something else ... perhaps only a pulse is applied

Comment: @Jstola I do not believe it is controlled by a microcontroller. The single wire from the sensor changes voltage from 0.15 to 0.10 when a hand is placed on the faucet. There is no power going to the sensor. The relay is only 0.75'' x 0.5'' x 0.25''. I considered a resistor for the behavior of the valve shutting off after a set time, there may be a better way.

Comment: Show picture of relay wires and contacts or part number

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I've edited a photo in to the original post. The 6v power has two wires (positive/neutral), the sensor wire has only a single wire that changes from 0.15v to 0.10v when a hand touches the faucet. There is no part number, and the wires are covered completely with exoxy.

Comment: My guess is the water pressure makes this valve latching in either direction with a pulse of solenoid current in either direction to toggle the valve polarity. So a touch sense causes the circuit to set  and timer RC delay to a FET to release but a 1shot pulse for each event perhaps with an inadequate Reed Relay and clamp diode. What is the solenoid resistance?